# Amchart 4: Remove grid line when value = 0

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I created a multiple axis chart using Amchart 4, but the grid line for second valueAxis cannot remove even I set

```
valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
```

[image]

Can someone help me to remove the line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The zero line is controlled by the `baseGrid`. You have to disable that one too.

```
valueAxis.renderer.baseGrid.disabled = true;
```

[Documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/#Zero_line)